# C# DialogForm opening when calling for mainForm

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

I have a problem with my dialogForm. This is the code that opens my dialogForm (this is a login form) when my mainForm starts to run.

```
    private void indexForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startForm loginForm = new startForm();
        loginForm.ShowDialog();
        indexUsername.Text = klasseGebruikersnaam.gebruikersnaam;          
    }
```

So when my indexForm (Main form) starts , it first loads a dialogForm, which is my login form.

Now my problem is that whenever I try to acces the mainForm from another form using this code (for example when I click a button):

```
        this.Hide();
        indexForm inf = new indexForm();
        inf.Show();
```

The dialogForm pops up again. So I want to show my mainForm but , when I load my mainForm my dialogForm always pops up.

Any way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is something wrong in your code above. If the indexForm is your main form, calling new indexForm creates a new instance of the indexForm, don't confuse this instance with the one that has been created by the initial Application.Run. They are two different variables of the same type but not the same instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading your `loginForm` from your Main Form's Load event.  Which is always going to fire after the constructor of the `Main Form` is called.  Typically you will want to launch the `loginForm` from somewhere *before* the Main Form is loaded.  You could do this in your `Program.cs` file and make it the main entry point of the program.  Or just simply check if the user is already logged in.

Here is an example of both:

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main()
{
    //Auto-generated code that VS writes for you

    using (var loginForm = new LoginForm())
    {
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes) //Presumably it would only return Yes if the login was successful.
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm()); //Or however you call your main form
        }
    }
}
```

Of you can just put a property on the Main Form that determines if the user is logged in.  Then you can call it in the `Load` event still.

**Load Event**

```
if(!this.UserLoggedIn)
{
    loginForm.ShowDialog();
    //Do something with the dialog result.
}
```

In my opinion it is better to user the `Program.cs` approach because if the user fails to login correctly, you can just exit or handle it as needed without loading your Main Form at all.  The way you currently have it, the main form *must* load before the login form is shown, which could be problematic.

Comment: can't quite get the program.cs approach working. What do you actually mean with the "loginCredentials" in the new MainForm?

Comment: @user3644837 Don't copy and paste directly, you probably don't need the login credentials, that is just what *I would do* to pass the users role etc to the main form in case you have different versions for different roles etc...  I commented the example to hopefully explain a bit better.

Comment: Typically in OOP we want to have our classes do *one specific* thing.  So all of your login logic should be handled in the `loginForm` class (or even better a separated logic class that handles authentication which your login form would use).

Comment: This is the problem when I enter your **var** loginForm... I get errors. But now I see that you begin your 'program.cs' with **private void Main(string[] args)** , while mine begins with **static void Main()**. Oh maybe I didn't clarify, but I'm working with visual studio winforms, not vb.

Comment: @user3644837 Those are compiler errors and they should be telling you exactly what is wrong, mine is C# winforms also.  Likely you are trying to cut and paste my code directly, but mine is just pseudo code.  You will need to use your class names etc...  I did however write the signature of `Main()` wrong.  It is now corrected.

Comment: @EvanL there is something fundamentally wrong in the question code. Look at my comment there, because if it is like I think it is then there is a bigger problem here

Comment: @Steve That's why I'm trying to get him to refactor it into `Program.cs`.  His code as is is going to keep creating instances of Main Form, then Login Form, then Main Form etc...

Comment: Thanks for all the help , but I'm not able to fix this with the comments provided here. Maybe abit out of my league.

Comment: Anway after a half hour of google searching i found that this didn't work because I didn't set my dialog.result button and form acceptButton properly. After that this solution works perfectly thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should remove that code from your main form and call it before showing the main form.
Or you could simply set a global variable that keeps the info for the current logged in  user and, if that variable is not null, don't call again the login form

So, supppose that you login form prepare an instance variable of type LoggedinUser

```
public class LoggedinUser
{
     public string NickName {get;set;}
     public string UserRole {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

then in an utility class (or in your index form) you could have a static variable

```
public static LoggedinUser currentOperator = null;
```

in your in index_form you could write

```
if(GlobaClass.currentOperator == null)
{
    using(startForm loginForm = new startForm())
    {
        if(loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           GlobalClass.currentOperator = loginForm.LoggedUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice with the examples, this is one of *very few* times where globals are a good idea ;)

Comment: Usually globals are dangerous, but they are not always avoidable (or convenient to avoid them). When the global variable represents a single entity required for the lifetime of the application (or when its changes are easily monitored (login/logout) then there is an opportunity for them

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to add a check to see if the user is logged in around the

```
loginForm.ShowDialog();
```

something like

```
if(!UserLoggedIn())
{
    loginForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: So I need to put this check in my mainForm load event right?

Comment: yes, note that the UserLoggedIn method is something you will need to put together